# why the "which" below is in plural form?

Tags: grammatical-number

"Personal fulfillment is achievement of life goals which **are** important to an individual, in contrast to the goals of society, family and other collective obligations. Personal fulfillment is an ongoing journey for a human individual."

I think it should be "which **is** important", because the "which" right now refer to the "achievement" and the achievement is in the singular form.

Please correct me if I am wrong

Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_fulfillment

Answer (score 3):

I just realised that the "which" is refer to the "life goals", not the "achievement".

Comment: You've got it!!

Comment: You need the word *that* not *which*.

Answer (score -1):

Replacing "which" with "that" would be better here as the clause following "are" is restrictive, i.e., removing this clause would change the meaning of this statement. This would also further simplify the use of "are. "

Answer (score -1):

*Which are important to an individual* is an adjective clause. The Subordinating linker WHICH- American preference for THAT conceded, refers to the antecedent, Goals and hence requires a plural verb. Of course as suggested by you the noun phrase, Achievement of life goals can as well be the subject of the adjective clause and in that case a singular verb can as well be appropriate. It all depends on the intended meaning.